# UI-Router: move from child state to sibling without reloading parent controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I use `$state.go` in a child of a given parent to move to another child state of that same parent, the controller associated with the parent seems to always reload, is there any way to avoid this behavior, only triggering the controller of the newly selected child state?

Comment: By default, when navigating from parent.child1 to parent.child2 - parent is **not** reloaded. That's the default. Check if you did not change that behaviour (e.g. with reload : true setting)

Comment: What I'm doing is: `$state.go('^.' + childName, params, {location: false});`

Answer (score 1):

Ok turns out reloading was happening because I was supplying a parameter of the parent in addition to parameters for the children.